# Не работает SwipeFefreshLayout в Fragment

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, framelayout

Добрый день!
Есть приложение с фрагментом, пытаюсь в него поместить SwipeRefresh, но никак не выходит. Проблема в том, что нет даже отображения этого обновления сверху, вообще ничего. Что я делаю не так?

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="hfad.com.ovdinfo.TopFragment"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout_news"
android:clickable="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refreshing">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Recycler_View"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

В TopFragment.class есть и

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refreshing);
```

и

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new ParseTask().execute();
            getAllNewsList();
        }
    });
```

Comment: в метод onRefresh добавьте mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)
а вообще это нужно добавить в метод preExecute() asyncTask'а

Comment: Добавил и туда и туда и поочередно и вместе, всё равно, 0 реакции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в том, что я в OnCreate возвращал

```
return mRecyclerView;
```

А надо возвращать view

```
return view;
```

Спасибо всем за огромный интерес к проблеме, очень приятно удивило количество сообщений, столько полезной информации! Ребята, вы лучшие!